# How to suppress warnings of hardcoded link reported by sphinx.ext.extlink extension?

Tags: python-sphinx

After 4.4.0, Sphinx introduce a function for checking [if hardcoded URLs can be replaced with extlinks](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/9800), I got a lot of warning when build my documentation.

I don't want to replace my links to extlink's role. How can I suppress them?

Comment: Okay, this issue is already disscussing in https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/10112 , just waiting for conclusion.